# I would like to get this code to upload pictures to 2 different folders

Tags: asp-classic

We are trying to use persits upload code to upload pictures to 2 different folders. It works when uploading to just one folder but not 2 folders.

Essentially, we have two folders, one is called img and the other is a subdirectory of img called small.

We grab 1 picture and upload same picture into both img and small folders.

So far, the picture gets uploaded to small folder but not to img folder.

Below is the relevant code followed by a link where I got my sample code from.

```
'Upload.asp
<form name="form" action="process.asp" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
 <Table>
     <tr>
     <td class="body1" div align="right">Attach for IMG folder:</div></td>
     <td><INPUT NAME="file1" TYPE="FILE" value="" SIZE=30></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="body1" div align="right">Attach for SMALL folder:</div></td>
     <td><INPUT NAME="file2" TYPE="FILE" value="" SIZE=30></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <hr color="silver">

  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center">
    <input  type="image" name="submit" id="submit2" title="submit to db." border="0" src="images/submitbutton.jpg" width="142" height="47" alt="Submit Button">
        </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

'Process.asp
<%
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
' Limit file size to 5000000 bytes, throw an exception if file is larger
Upload.SetMaxSize 5000000, True

' Save to memory. Path parameter is omitted
Count = Upload.Save


' Two images must be selected
If Count <> 2 Then
   Response.Write "You must select 2 jpeg files."
   Response.End
End If

' Intercept all exceptions to display user-friendly error
On Error Resume Next


' Create two folders, ignore "already exists" error
Upload.CreateDirectory Server.MapPath("/img"), True
Upload.CreateDirectory Server.MapPath("img/small"), True

' Obtain File objects
Set File1 = Upload.Files("file1")
Set File2 = Upload.Files("file2")

' Build name from session ID
'Name = Session.SessionID

' Save
'File1.SaveAs (Server.MapPath("/img/" & File1.Ext))
'File2.SaveAs (Server.MapPath("/img/small/" & File2.Ext))

' Copy file 1 to img folder
File1.Copy (Server.MapPath("/img/" & File1.Ext))
' Delete from temp folder
File1.Delete

' Copy file 2 to small folder
File1.Copy (Server.MapPath("/small/" & File1.Ext))
' Delete from temp folder
File2.Delete


For Each File in Upload.Files
   If File.ImageType <> "JPG" Then
      Response.Write "The image type you are uploading is not a JPGE image."
      File.Delete
      Response.End
   End If
Next

  Dim objConn,connectstr,objRS,prodset,specialset,bncatset,featureset

  connectstr = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=scartmil.db.8911524.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=scartmil; User ID=999999; Password=8888;"
  Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  objConn.Open connectstr

catdescription = Upload.Form(trim("catdescription"))
pcode          = Upload.Form("pcode")
pname          = Upload.Form(trim("pname"))
pdescription   = Upload.Form(trim("pdescription"))
pPhoto         = Upload.Form("pPhoto")
cstock         = Upload.Form("cstock")
cprice         = Upload.Form("UnitPrice")

'sanitize to avoid sql injection
catdescription = replace(catdescription,"'","''",1,-1,1)
pcode = replace(pcode,"'","''",1,-1,1)
pname = replace(pname,"'","''",1,-1,1)
pdescription = replace(pdescription,"'","''",1,-1,1)
pPhoto = replace(pPhoto,"'","''",1,-1,1)
cstock = replace(cstock,"'","''",1,-1,1)
cprice = replace(cprice,"'","''",1,-1,1)

'response.write cprice
'response.end
sql = "INSERT INTO products (ccategory, " & _
                             "ccode, " & _
                             "cname, " & _
                             "cdescription, " & _
                             "cimageurl, " & _
                             "cstock, " & _
                             "cprice) " & _
                 "VALUES (" & _
                         ""&catdescription&", " & _
                         "'"&pcode&"', " & _
                         "'"&pname&"', " & _
                         "'"&pdescription&"', " & _
                         "'"&pPhoto&"', " & _
                         ""&cstock&", " & _
                         ""&cprice&")"
                    'response.write sql
                    'response.end
       set rs = objConn.Execute(sql)

'ok record in, now retrieve the primary key

sql = "SELECT products.catalogID FROM products ORDER BY products.catalogID DESC"
'response.write sql
'response.end
set prodset = objConn.execute(sql)
if not prodset.EOF then
bCatalog = prodset("CatalogID")
end if


sql= "INSERT INTO bndCategoryProduct (bCategoryId, " & _
                                       "bCatalogId) " & _
                 "VALUES (" & _
                         ""&catdescription&", " & _
                         ""&bCatalog&")"
                    'response.write sql
                    'response.end

set bncatset = objConn.execute(sql)



objConn.Close
Set objConn=Nothing



%>
```

Here is the persits link:

http://www.aspupload.com/manual_memory.html

Please don't pay attention to the insert code; it works fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't post you db string/password on here.

Comment: Is all the rest of that database manipulation code really relevant?  Please just include only relevant chunks of code so we don't have to wade through it all.  But since you have posted it can I point out that your attempt at SQL injection protection is inadequate.  Learn to use parameterised queries instead of all that mucking about with replacing ' which is very prone to bugs and holes as your code demonstrates.

Comment: @Chidi Okeh - To also go off of what Michael was stating, you should probably change your DB PW now.  Users of this site can view it in the changelog still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the same write permissions to both folders?  also, did you notice your folders are different. If you do have the permissions set correctly, the other issue I see is your folders.   You have /img and img/small  Those could potentially be two different img folders.

Upload.CreateDirectory Server.MapPath("/img"), True
Upload.CreateDirectory Server.MapPath("img/small"), True

The next potential problem I see is in the code below.  Just under ' Copy file 2 to small folder you have File1.copy.   Shouldn't that be File2.Copy.

```
'# Copy file 1 to img folder
File1.Copy (Server.MapPath("/img/" & File1.Ext))
'# Delete from temp folder
File1.Delete

'# Copy file 2 to small folder
File1.Copy (Server.MapPath("/small/" & File1.Ext))
'# Delete from temp folder
File2.Delete
```

Comment: small folder is sub directory of img. Small folder is inside the img folder and permission was set on img and set for small to inherit that permission.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I see:

Both copy commands use file1
They also don't specify the name, only extension.
Why not use the saveas method?
Comment out 'on error resume next' and wrap folder creation code in if/then and check if folder exists. Then you can see your errors

Comment: Thank you Michael. You said that I didn't specify the name, only extension. What exactly do you mean? I thought name from markup is file1 and file2?

Comment: File1.Copy (Server.MapPath("/img/" & File1.Ext))
File1.Ext is only the extension.
Also, add ' before "on error resume next". That way, it will throw an error. If you have a permissions error as Padas said, it will let you know.